# the efficient approach to generate submatrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The following is a function that can return sub-matries from two given matries. The position of generating these sub-matries are the same for both input matries. The input matries are of `Numpy array`. I just would like to know are there more elegant ways to fulfill the same type of task as this function provided.

```
def seg(ma1,ma2,size):
  rowN = len(ma1)           
  colN = len(ma1[0])         
  dim1 = random.randint(0,rowN-size)
  dim2 = random.randint(0,colN-size)
  return ma1[dim1:dim1+size,dim2:dim2+size], ma2[dim1:dim1+size,dim2:dim2+size]
```

Comment: The only thing that I think would add "elegance" is to do `(rowN,colN) = ma1.size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative approach, we could create the indexing ranges with [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) and index into the input arrays with those, like so -

```
idx = np.ix_(np.arange(size)+dim1,np.arange(size)+dim2)
out = ma1[idx], ma2[idx]
```

---

Another approach could be suggested using [`np.mgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) to create the dense row and column indices. This would require more memory than the previous one, but probably closer to the original code though shorter. Here's how it would look like -

```
R,C = np.mgrid[dim1:dim1+size,dim2:dim2+size]
out = ma1[R,C], ma2[R,C]
```

Another way to "shift" the elegance into `np.mgrid` and push out workload into the latter indexing part would be like so -

```
R,C = np.mgrid[:size,:size]
out = ma1[R+dim1,C+dim2], ma2[R+dim1,C+dim2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to do `rowN, colN = ma1.shape` instead of

rowN = len(ma1)
colN = len(ma1[0])

Also, you might want to seed your random number generator.